# redirect non-https to https infinite loop on android browser

Tags: android, .htaccess, url-rewriting, infinite-loop, android-browser

The following lines and all similar codes makes android browser throw error "too many redirects"

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

I couldn't find any solution to resolve this problem and I don't believe there is a solution. Only I wonder why this error occure? Does anyone know source of the error?

Comment: Clear your browser's cache.

Comment: I clear the cache already, I try different devices but not change the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you installed certificate but you did not install CA certificates this problem occurs.

CA certificates are required and you will have trouble with this little mistake when you never expected.

Answer (score 1):

Try following code with your .htaccess, it redirects your request with https:// to proper https:// links and if ssl is not enabled that redirects it to http:// links

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```